# Как сделать такой эффект в css?

Tags: html, css, css3, sass

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как измнетить цвет текста в цвет div, если текст попадает внутрь div, но при этом меняется только та часть текста которая попадает в div.
Цвет div: #FFF
Задний фон div: #004293
Цвет текста который попадает в div:  #004293

При этом это должно быть адаптивным

Comment: В этом случае сделано видимо так: текст `Професс` помещён в один контейнер, а `иональное` - в другой, и для этих контейнеров настроен разный цвет текста.

Comment: В мобильной версии не только Професс но и нижние текста, так что думаю это не так реализованно

Comment: Просто с нижней строкой сделано то же самое, т. е. буквы `обслуж` находятся в контейнере с таким же классом, как и `Професс`.

Comment: Для "адаптации" достаточно понять как ширина "левой" части "зависит" от "синего круга"... Это просто две полоски, где левая часть должна иметь определенный размер и равнение текста по правому краю. А "правая" часть занимает все оставшееся пространство и имеет обычное равнение текста по левому краю...

Answer (score 3):

Интересная задачка. Похожа на тестовое задание) У меня во так вишло.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.block {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-left: 50px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  background-color: #000;
  min-height: 140px;
  color: #004293;
  filter: invert(100%);
}

.block:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 140px;
  height: 140px;
  background-color: #ffbd6c;
  clip-path: path('M70 0C51.4 0 34.5 7.3 22 19.1V121c12.5 11.7 29.4 19 48 19 38.7 0 70-31.3 70-70S108.7 0 70 0z');
}

.text {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 24px;
  color: #ffbd6c;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <p class="text">Професиональное</p>
  <p class="text">обслуживание <span>Вашего</span> бизнеса</p>
</div>
```

Дальше уже дело техники. Оно масштабируеться.